# MongoDB (mac os catalina) doesn't appear "Waiting for connection"

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina

I run `mongo` and get the output:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("446d44ce-8342-40ec-a308-667a28ce10a0") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.1
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting: 
        2020-12-16T20:36:30.592-03:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
        2020-12-16T20:36:30.592-03:00: Soft rlimits too low
        2020-12-16T20:36:30.592-03:00:         currentValue: 256
        2020-12-16T20:36:30.592-03:00:         recommendedMinimum: 64000
---
---
        Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
        metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

        The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
        and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
        improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

        To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
        To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---
```

In another terminal I run `mongod` and get:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.120-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.142-03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.142-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.146-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":7051,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"********-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.147-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.147-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"19.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.147-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.150-03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.150-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.155-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.156-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.156-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-25T22:25:54.156-03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

But I don't see the message "waiting for connections on port 27017".
I tried everything I found on the internet! I installed homebrew to install MongoDB.

Comment: Also when I put the command ~ % brew services list   it returns an error messages

Comment: mongodb-community     error   myname /Users/myname/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

Comment: mongodb-community@4.2 error   myname /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.2/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2.plist

Answer (score 0):

From the output you get from running `mongo`, we can see that you're able to successfully connect to a preexisting `mongod` process. When you try to run `mongod` there's a log stating `Address already in use`, supporting the idea that there is already a `mongod` process running. I'm unclear on what issue you're experiencing.